# All users/database passwords changed after Plesk backup restore

Tags: mysql, backup, restore, plesk, dedicated-server

I recently crashed my dedicated server and had to format it and reinstall a clean Ubuntu/Plesk/Apache...

Thankfully I had a full Plesk backup which I was able to restore without issue, and now all of the files, databases, users and settings seem to be back correctly.

Problem is for some reason, all of the passwords are no longer valid, be it MySQL, FTP or Plesk ones (meaning most sites won't display since they don't have access to the databases anymore).

Is this intended? And is there a way to fix it? It would be very time consuming to go and changes every single one.

Thanks

OS : ‪Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Plesk  :    12.5.30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have set a password while taking the backup and while restoring the backup, you have unselected the option:

https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/administrator-guide/backing-up-and-restoration/restoring-data-from-backup-archives.59263/

> Backup security settings. If the backup was protected with a password,
>   enter the password in the Password field.  If you have forgotten your
>   password, clear the Provide the password option. Note that in this
>   case, some sensitive data will not be restored properly. For example,
>   user passwords will be replaced with random ones, information about
>   already installed APS apps will be lost, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't exactly the problem but close :  
I went to check the password settings after reading this and there's an additional note that I think is missing from your link : if you choose to not password protect your backup, the passwords will not be recoverable, as if you had forgotten the password (since the backup is insecure). That was the problem here.